# Turn off display in Raspbian Lite 11 (bullseye)

Tags: display, dsi

I have the "lite" (without GUI) version of Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) installed on my Raspberry Pi 4. I am using it with some third party  Waveshare 5" touchscreen LCD display connected to the DSI port. In order to save energy, I would like to activate and deactivate the display by pushing a button.

Running

```
vcgencmd display_power 0
```

does not disable the display but only reduce the brightness.

```
tvservice -o
```

gives an error, stating that

```
tvservice is not supported when using the vc4-kms-v3d driver.
Similar features are available with standard linux tools
such as modetest from libdrm-tests.
```

So, is there a way to turn off the display completely?

Comment: `modetest` is in fact in `libdrm-tests` (ie. install with `apt install libdrm-tests`) -- have you looked at that?  I doubt though, that these screens can be powered down without adding hardware between it and the source (which probably isn't feasible if you have the screen mounted right on the pi).

Comment: `activate and deactivate the display by pushing a button` ... buy a latching pushbutton ... wire it in series with the LCD power pin

Comment: @goldilocks It seems that it has been possible so far. There might be a solution, no idea whether it works though. https://github.com/SvenVD/rpisurv/issues/143#issuecomment-1066167704

Comment: And this, it seems like a solution (based on same 'hack') https://www.cnx-software.com/2021/12/09/raspberry-pi-zero-2-w-power-consumption/